# correspond values between two images in opencv / c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new in image processing and opencv. I have two images. I want to find correspond values in the image 2 with the image 1. and then show it. is there any function in opencv to find correspond values between images?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "correspand values"? The same RGB Values in two images? Or the same structure? Please tell us some more about your problem and/or add an example image to your question.

Comment: the same values in two images.both of them are gray scale.

Comment: I have two gray scale images.
I want to find all values in image 2 which are correspond to nonzero values in the image 1 and then I want to show it.

Comment: Only to nonezero Values or to the same nonzero Values?

Answer (score 4):

```
Mat corrVals;
bitwise_and(image2, image1>0, corrVals);
```

image1>0 will create temporary binary image with values 0 and 255. Than the only thing you need is to perform AND operation between pixels of your images, and store result somewhere. This is done by bitwise_and.

This is similar to approach suggested by @Mailerdaimon but uses much cheaper operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can threshold you image1 such that all Values you want are `1` and all other are `0`.

Than you [multiply](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multiply) `image1` with `image2`.

```
cv::multiply(image1, image2, result, scale, dtype)
```

This will return an image with all values greater than zero from `image2` that are marked in `image1`.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without looking at your images. This is a well studied problem in computer vision and OpenCV contains several algorithms for this. The problem you're looking at can be very easy or very hard, depending on:

- your images, are the normal images? just shapes? binary?
- where on the images lie the corresponding pixels
- how fast you need this to run
- how much variation there is between images, is it exactly the same pixel value?
- is there camera movement?
- is there variation in illumination?

You can start by looking at [stereo matching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/stereo.html) and [optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) inside OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for the points. actually, I am not sure that I can publish the images or not. I need to ask my professor first. I can just say right now that I am working on depth images and what I am trying is to find a way to reduce the noise in this type of data. 
may I have your email address?

Comment: would you please explain even in brief that how movement of the camera can affect on selecting a proper threshold value?
thanks in advance.